# How can I update wifi on Ubuntu 17.10 server?

Tags: server, wireless

I recently updated my home wifi network router's SSID and password. How do I update my wifi network configuration in Ubuntu Server 17.10?

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, but if you want to do this sort of thing, please post your answer as an answer and not as part of the question. I removed the answer from your question (you can see it by clicking on the ["edit history"](https://askubuntu.com/posts/992162/revisions) link), but please do post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

After a LOT of digging around for documentation I gave up and located a file with my old SSID and managed to work it out from there. I'm sharing for use by others:

Ubuntu Server is using netplan (the documents). To update I did the following:

1) updated the yaml file with my configuration

```
sudo vi /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
```

..

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wls1:
      dhcp4: yes
      access-points:
        [MY_SSID]:
          password: [MY_PASSWORD]
```

2) Applied the changes:

```
sudo netplan apply
```

3) Restarted the network interface:

```
sudo ifconfig wls1 down
sudo ifconfig wls1 up
```

I hope this saves others some searching. (I'm also open to feedback!)

Good luck!